# .exe doesn't do anything after using cx_Freeze to make PyQt app executable

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, pyqt4, cx-freeze

I have big GUIapp which contains lot of libraries such us PyQT4,  matplotlib, pandas and etc...
I've used cx_Freeze to make it to make it executable and everything went smoothly.
After opening .exe it just doesn't do anything.
pls see my setup.py file.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

packages = ['pyhdb','paramiko','sshtail','smtplib','pandas','email','xml']
include_files = ["Models","Views", "Controllers","images","graphs","green.png","red.png","files", "resource_rc.py"]
excludes=["tkinter"]


base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

setup(
   name="DMO App",
   version="1.0",
   description="Dmo App",
   options={"build_exe":{"packages":packages,"include_files":include_files}},

   executables=[Executable("main.py",base=base)]
)
```

Any suggestions what was the problem?

Comment: Try to start the executable from the command-line and see if it generates any error message.

Comment: I did that already and no any errors ))).

Comment: What does your main.py code look like? Does it include a check for __main__? If so, this is a known issue which will be resolved. You can work around it until that happens.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having exact same issue.